# Pass ng-template into component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-template, teradata-covalent

I am facing the problem, that I need to pass multiple ng-template into another component as a template, example:

```
<app-datatable>
   <ng-template tdDataTableTemplate="description" let-value="value" let-row="row" let-column="column">
    <p matTooltip="{{ row[column ]}}">{{ row[column] }}</p>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template tdDataTableTemplate="vendorName" let-value="value">
    <p matTooltip="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</p>
  </ng-template>
</app-datatable>
```

**app-datatable** is my component and I need to pass these templates to it as a template.

[image]

**td-data-table** is Teradata covalent DataTable component. It has functionality, that I can template each column with **ng-template**. But I want to pass **ng-template** through my component into **td-data-table** - hope it makes sence

**Solution:**

I didn't manage to find Covalent way solution. But I've managed to rewrite Teradata grid to custom grid, which allows me more control over it. Here is Stackblitz: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-covalent-custom-datatable?file=app%2Fdatatable%2Fdatatable.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and managed to fix it with the following:

In datatable.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-table',
    templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.scss']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnChanges, AfterContentInit {
    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        for (let template of this.templates.toArray()) {
            if (!template.tdDataTableTemplate) {
                continue
            }
            this.tdDataTable._templateMap.set(template.tdDataTableTemplate, template.templateRef)
        }
    }

    @ViewChild(TdDataTableComponent) tdDataTable;
    @ContentChildren(TdDataTableTemplateDirective) templates;
}
```

This mimics how `TdDataTableCompponent` handles the templates under the hood.

Also, for completeness, I spoke to the OP on the [covalent gitter](https://gitter.im/Teradata/covalent?source=all-rooms-list) and they said that they solved it by rewriting the data table from the individual covalent components. They shared a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-covalent-custom-datatable?file=app%2Fdatatable%2Fdatatable.component.html).